# Upload file from local machine (Windows) to HDFS via cURL: Protocol mismatch

Tags: hadoop, curl, hdfs

**What I want to achieve**
I want to move a file from my local Windows machine to HDFS using cURL. In my case HDFS is running on a virtual machine

**What's not working**
I'm using following command

```
curl -i -X PUT "http://ip:port/webhdfs/v1/...?op=CREATE"
```

I'm executing the above from Windows Command Prompt which I cd'ed to the folder containing the testfile.txt. The command returns the following

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
Protocol mismatch.
```

Edit: According to this [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Create_and_Write_to_a_File) I should be getting a response as

```
HTTP/1.1 307 TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
Location: http://<DATANODE>:<PORT>/webhdfs/v1/<PATH>?op=CREATE...
Content-Length: 0
```

Then I should be able to run the second step as follows

```
curl -i -X PUT -T testfile.txt "http://ip:port/webhdfs/v1/data?op=CREATE..."
```

**Question**
How can I successfully upload a file on hdfs using curl?

Comment: What's `:proxy`? Based on your response, you've curled  to an SSH server, not the namenode. In any case, uploading is a two step process https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html#Create_and_Write_to_a_File

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It should be `port` and not `proxy`, I fixed it. The comment, that I curl an SSH server and not the namenode is probably the crucial part here. Which `<HOST>:<PORT>` am I supposed to use / Where do I find the host:port of the namenode?

Comment: I found it. 50070 is the standard port for the first part, 50075 (will be part of the output of part 1) is the port for the second part

Comment: So, it works now?

Comment: yes, it does. Many thanks :) If you sum it up in an answer I'll accept it. I'm using the Hortonworks Sandbox HDP 2.6.3 btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the Protocol Mismatch is given by cricket_007 in the comments

> Based on your response, you've curled to an SSH server, not the namenode.

This was due to a wrong port in the `curl -i -X PUT "http://ip:port/webhdfs/v1/...?op=CREATE"` statement.

The default port is **50070** on the hortonworks sandboxs HDP distribution.